# to send email using Intent

Tags: android, email

In my project,I have retrieved my call log and sms Data and want it to send through email in background.
Retrieved data code is:-(in WakefulBroadcastReceiver)

```
private Context mContext;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        mContext = context;

        getSMSData();
        getCallLogData();

    }

    private void getSMSData() {

        ContentResolver contentResolver = mContext.getContentResolver();

        // use content://sms/inbox/ for received and content://sms/sent/ for sent messages
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/");

        String selection = "date BETWEEN ? AND ? ";
        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long pastThreeHour = currentTime - (AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HOUR * 3);
        String[] selectionArgs = { "" + pastThreeHour, "" + currentTime };

        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, null, selection, selectionArgs, "date DESC");

        if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

                String number = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("address")); // check for null
                String date = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("date")); // convert to date its long
                String message_text = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("body"));
                String type = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("type")); // check type and get names

                // send email from here
                sendSMSEmail(number, date, message_text, type);
            }
        }
        cursor.close();
    }

    private void getCallLogData() {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://call_log/calls");

        String[] projection = new String[] { Calls.TYPE, Calls.NUMBER, Calls.DATE, Calls.CACHED_NAME, Calls.DURATION };

        String selection = "date BETWEEN ? AND ? ";
        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long pastThreeHour = currentTime - (AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HOUR * 3);
        String[] selectionArgs = { "" + pastThreeHour, "" + currentTime };

        Cursor cursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, "date DESC");

        if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

                String num = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NUMBER));
                // convert long date to date
                String date = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE));

                String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME));
                String duration = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DURATION));

                int type = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.TYPE)));

                String typeName = null;

                switch (type) {
                    case 1:
                        typeName = "Incoming";
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        typeName = "Outgoing";
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        typeName = "Missed";
                        break;
                }

                sendCallEmail(num, date, name, duration, typeName);

            }
        }
    }

    private void sendCallEmail(String num, String date, String name, String duration, String typeName) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    private void sendSMSEmail(String number, String date, String message_text, String type) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Actually I can't understand how to send these retrieved data to my mail id.
Mail Id should be provided by the user only.
Please help me to send mail.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: send the retrieved data via web service and email will be handled at web end.
because you cannot send email in background

Comment: sorry sir,I have no idea to do this.can u please help me out?

Comment: Use JavaMail api to send email. Its pure Java code you can send it in background using Service

Comment: @HardikTrivedi then I have to make a service class along with it ?

Comment: Yes barun. First try to achieve functionality in Java class like we do public static void main(Stirng rgs[]). Then move that code to Android Service

Answer (score 0):

```
 Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
 email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Email Subject");
 email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "email_body");//Share your call logs or sms data in the body

// need this to prompts email client only
email.setType("message/rfc822");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client :"));
```

Comment: It will send your data via your built-in email client. Users have to choose the email client. your built-in email client will surely send the data in background. If you want to send email without built-in app then use  `Java Mail API`